# Pandas Structured 2D Data to XYZ Table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create an xyz table from a structured grid representation of data in a Pandas DataFrame.

What I have is:

```
# Grid Nodes/indices
x=np.arange(5)
y=np.arange(5)
# DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,5), columns=x, index=y)

>>>df
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.536047  0.673782  0.935536  0.853286  0.916081
1  0.884820  0.438207  0.070120  0.292445  0.789046
2  0.899633  0.822928  0.445154  0.643797  0.776154
3  0.682129  0.974159  0.078451  0.306872  0.689137
4  0.117842  0.770962  0.861076  0.429738  0.149199
```

I want to convert the above DataFrame to this DataFrame structure:

```
>>>df
x y val
0 0 #
0 1 #
...
4 4 #
```

I can create a for loop to do this but I believe I should be able to do this using the `pivot`, `stack`, or some other built-in method though but I am not getting it from the documentation. It seems to create multilevel DataFrames which I do not want. Bonus points for converting it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dff = df.stack().reset_index(name="values")`
`pd.pivot_table(index="level_0",columns="level_1",values="values",data=dff)`

First part is taken from the previous answer to be used for the unstacking part.
First one is for stacking and second for unstacking.

```
    level_0 level_1 values
0   0   0   0.536047
1   0   1   0.673782
2   0   2   0.935536
3   0   3   0.853286
4   0   4   0.916081
5   1   0   0.884820
6   1   1   0.438207
7   1   2   0.070120
8   1   3   0.292445
9   1   4   0.789046
10  2   0   0.899633
11  2   1   0.822928
12  2   2   0.445154
13  2   3   0.643797
14  2   4   0.776154
15  3   0   0.682129
16  3   1   0.974159
17  3   2   0.078451
18  3   3   0.306872
19  3   4   0.689137
20  4   0   0.117842
21  4   1   0.770962
22  4   2   0.861076
23  4   3   0.429738
24  4   4   0.149199

# Unstacking

level_1 0          1           2            3          4
level_0                 
0   0.536047    0.673782    0.935536    0.853286    0.916081
1   0.884820    0.438207    0.070120    0.292445    0.789046
2   0.899633    0.822928    0.445154    0.643797    0.776154
3   0.682129    0.974159    0.078451    0.306872    0.689137
4   0.117842    0.770962    0.861076    0.429738    0.149199
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
In [4474]: df = df.stack().reset_index(name='value').rename(columns={'level_0':'x', 'level_1': 'y'})

In [4475]: df
Out[4475]: 
    x  y     value
0   0  0  0.772210
1   0  1  0.921495
2   0  2  0.903645
3   0  3  0.980514
4   0  4  0.156923
5   1  0  0.516448
6   1  1  0.121148
7   1  2  0.394074
8   1  3  0.532963
9   1  4  0.369175
10  2  0  0.605971
11  2  1  0.712189
12  2  2  0.866299
13  2  3  0.174830
14  2  4  0.042236
15  3  0  0.350161
16  3  1  0.100152
17  3  2  0.049185
18  3  3  0.808631
19  3  4  0.562624
20  4  0  0.090918
21  4  1  0.713475
22  4  2  0.723183
23  4  3  0.569887
24  4  4  0.980238
```

For converting it back, use [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
In [4481]: unstacked_df = df.pivot('x', 'y')

In [4482]: unstacked_df
Out[4482]: 
      value                                        
y         0         1         2         3         4
x                                                  
0  0.772210  0.921495  0.903645  0.980514  0.156923
1  0.516448  0.121148  0.394074  0.532963  0.369175
2  0.605971  0.712189  0.866299  0.174830  0.042236
3  0.350161  0.100152  0.049185  0.808631  0.562624
4  0.090918  0.713475  0.723183  0.569887  0.980238
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. Yeah the key for me was the reset_index which removed the multi_level index I did not want. Bonus points: Would I use `unstack` for converting it back?

Comment: Thanks. I have to wait 10 mins but I'm going to accept ombk for converting and  converting back again.